# Firefox: Is there a way to prohibit or disable addons to open pages upon update?

Tags: firefox, browser-addons, notifications

I understand an addon can do virtually anything the browser API allows, but wouldn't this be treated by some browser setting? I've been skimming through `about:config` but didn't see anything like that.

Comment: Yes, that is the same problem described, although it doesn't have an acceptable solution( for me I have this trouble with `YouTube High Definition` addon) there.

Also I think this site is more fitting than the Mac-centered one.

What to do now?